# How to limit speed of internet connection on Android emulator?

Tags: android, performance, connection

I need to test app for work with slow internet connection.
How to simulate slow internet connection on Android emulator?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For **Android Studio** projects you can do the following:

If you need to change net speed temporarily, then on an emulator toolbar, click three dots (settings), go to **Cellular** tab and configure the network speed there. You need to have a recent Android Tools.

If you want to set this speed permanently for some emulator image:

1. Open menu **Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager**
2. Select/create your emulator avd image, click **Edit**
3. Click **Show Advanced Settings** button
4. Set the desired net speed

   Speeds for reference in increasing kbps:

   ```
                           UP       DOWN
                     -------- ----------
   gsm   GSM/CSD         14.4       14.4
   hscsd HSCSD           14.4       57.6
   gprs  GPRS            28.8       57.6
   umts  UMTS/3G        384.0      384.0
   edge  EDGE/EGPRS     473.6      473.6
   hsdpa HSDPA         5760.0   13,980.0
   lte   LTE         58,000.0  173,000.0
   evdo  EVDO        75,000.0  280,000.0
   full  No limit           ∞          ∞
   ```
5. Re-launch the emulator

**OLD ANSWER (obsolete)**

If you are working in Eclipse, go to **Run->Run Configurations**, select your run configuration and then go to "**Target**" Tab. There you will find a "**Network Speed**" combobox (under the "**Emulator Launch Parameters**" section).

If you are running emulator from command line, then you can use "**-netspeed**" cmd line parameter (run *emulator -help-netspeed* for overview of possible options)

Comment: is it possible to control that from within an application?

Comment: I don't think so. Of course perhaps you can make your application to process data it gets more slowly, but I suspect there's no way you can override a system's network speed. That would be awful if you could :)

Comment: Took me forever to find that Network Speed setting, cause there was no scroll bar on the side, and I didn't even think of resizing the window to find it. But thank you for the info.

Comment: Yeah, Eclpise sometimes screws up like this. I recall myself being in same situation regarding some other option :)

Comment: To configure network speed in the emulator 3 dots technique, choose Network type, then choose the type correponding to the speed using the table above.

Comment: Nicely answered!! Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Easiest way to tweak things while emulator is still up is to connect to the emulator using a terminal.  Just use telnet or netcat (interactively, you can just "telnet localhost 5554" and type "help" -- below examples show how to script it:

```
$ echo "network speed 100 100" | nc localhost 5554
$ echo "network status" | nc localhost 5554
Current network status:
  download speed:     100000 bits/s (12.2 KB/s)
  upload speed:       100000 bits/s (12.2 KB/s)
  minimum latency:  0 ms
  maximum latency:  0 ms
```

You can also set the delay/latency:

```
$ echo "network delay gprs" | nc localhost 5554
$ echo "network status" | nc localhost 5554
Current network status:
  download speed:     100000 bits/s (12.2 KB/s)
  upload speed:       100000 bits/s (12.2 KB/s)
  minimum latency:  150 ms
  maximum latency:  550 ms
```

Just makes it easier to do things at runtime and test various scenarios (via automation, manual testing, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unlike using run configuration this worked for me. I also like how you can check your current settings.

Comment: This is great. So much better to be able to alter the settings while you're running the emulator. Another command I found useful—it delays network by 2 seconds to test loading screens: `echo "network delay 2000" | nc localhost 5554`

Comment: FYI. now (2020) `echo` can not work as emulators require login `Android Console: Authentication required`,`Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate`

Comment: this solution not working at 2020 `Android Console: Authentication required`

Comment: it's still working, you follow the steps on the screen and paste in your authentication string `Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in 
'/Users/username/.emulator_console_auth_token'`. Once you copy that short code, do `nc localhost 5554` then `auth {code}`. The other thing is that this method does the same thing as `adb emu network delay 1000`

Comment: FYI the correct syntax to set both the download and upload speed is `network speed <up>:<down>`

Answer (score 6):

Appium [set network speed](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/network/network-speed/) with

```
adb emu network speed
```

example:

```
adb emu network speed gsm
```

all values(see [appium doc](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/network/network-speed/#json-parameters) ): gsm, hscsd, gprs, umts, edge, hsdpa, lte, evdo, full

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse :
**Run -> Run Configuratrions -> click!**

Select **Tab Target**. click!

Then there is an option **Network Speed**!

Set it to emulate whatever you want. :)

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to use the Mobile Network (not the WiFi) to experience internet speed change on your emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Run->Run Configurations**: there you can find **Emulator Launch Parameters** where you can set the internet speed

Answer (score 0):

On emulator go to

> Extended Controls -> Cellular -> Network Type

and set paramater as your per your requirement