# Installing Apple's Network Link Conditioner Tool

Tags: xcode, macos

I have installed xcode 4.3.1 on my machine running Lion.

I can't find the Network Link Conditioner tool anywhere.

I have checked the utilities folder, also the `xcode/contents/developer/*` directories.. no such luck.

Do I need to install specific components or has this tool been removed or renamed recently?

Comment: how to use it
in mac
http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2012/05/slow-your-apps-roll/
on ios 6+
http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2012/09/ios6-network-link-conditioner/

Comment: Sorry to see the "please delete me" as you're about to get a Great Question badge:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question

Comment: now it is called "Hardware IO tools"

Comment: the tools can now be found ("Hardware IO tools") here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: This link gives proper explanation of your question. http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/

Comment: Here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools

Answer (score 500):

It's in an additional download. Use this menu item:

> Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools...

and get ["Hardware IO Tools for Xcode"](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?name=Hardware%20IO%20Tools%20for%20Xcode%207).

For Xcode 8+, get ["Additional Tools for Xcode [version]"](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools).

Double-click on a `.prefPane` file to install. If you already have an older `.prefPane` installed, you'll need to remove it from `/Library/PreferencePanes`.

Comment: Just double-click the Network Link Conditioner.prefpane and OS X will  install it for you. (System Preferences will pop up and ask you about it.)

Comment: I mean, what is the standard place to install it on disk now that /Developer is no more?

Comment: As far as I know, preference panes never went in /Developer. (If you know differently, or if you're referring to something else, could you explain?) They are found in /System/Library/PreferencePanes, /Library/PreferencePanes, or ~/Library/PreferencePanes. If you double-click the prefpane, System Preferences will install it for you in one of the latter two places.

Comment: Everything worked except when trying to turn on the network link conditioner. In this case the window disappears and there is not throttling of the internet speed. Looking through the internet for this problem I found not solution. There were suggestions to add the files :
/system/library/launchdaemons/com.apple.networklinkconditioner.plist 
                         /usr/libexec/nlcd

but where shall i find those files.
Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: @Max I've copied them from another Mac OS X Lion machine which had Xcode installed. But I could find them only on a machine that came with a fresh installation of Lion.

Comment: Answer is correct, but the tool is completely broken - literally has zero effect on Mountain Lion (despite Apple's install notes saying this works on ML ). Thanks, Apple!

Comment: @Adam The Late July 2012 version worked for me on Montain Lion (the older ones did not).

Comment: Actually it does not crash the PrefPane anymore but still does nothing.

Comment: I just tried both the Late July 2012 and the latest 2013 version and neither has any effect at all.

Comment: Latest update works on Mavericks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100318/trouble-using-network-link-conditioner-on-os-x-mavericks

Comment: Just to clarify @KurtRevis's comment: Search for "Network Link Conditioner.prefPane" in spotlight, and select it. System Prefs will open and ask you if you want to install it.

Answer (score 40):

You can also install any of the Hardware IO Tools without installing XCode itself. Simply visit Apple's [Download Center](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and search for "Hardware IO".

Comment: BTW I've managed to get this installed on Snow Leopard by going to the Download Center directly. Thanks! -- Oh sorry. Maybe it doesn't work on Snow Leopard afterall. Though I could install and run it, but when I turned it on, it crashed.

Comment: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Hardware_IO_Tools_for_Xcode_7/Hardware_IO_Tools_for_Xcode_7.dmg

Comment: @bloudermilk that link does not work. slott, that is version-specific.

Answer (score 35):

Update on the answer **December 2019 Xcode 11.1.2**

> Apple has moved Network Link Conditioner Tool to additional tools for
>   Xcode

Go to the below link

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools

[image]

Install the dmg file, select hardware from installer

[image]

select Network Link conditioner prefpane
[image]

Comment: The page you’re looking for can’t be found.

Comment: Its still there pl check once more . Network Link conditioner is included along with "Additional tools for Xcode"

Answer (score 19):

The tools can now be found ("Hardware IO tools") here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Excellent answer - I really didn't want to install Xcode since I don't do native iOS or Mac development.

This was the only answer I've found that lets me install Network Link Conditioner without a multi-gigabyte download of Xcode.

Answer (score 16):

For Xcode 8 you gotta download a package named [`Additional Tools for Xcode 8`](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools)

For other versions (8.1, 8.2) get the package [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools)

Double click and open the `dmg` and go to `Hardware` directory. Double click on `Network Link Conditioner.prefPane`.

[image]

Click on install

[image]

Now Network Link Conditioner will be available in System Preferences.

For versions older than Xcode 8, the package to be downloaded is called `Hardware IO Tools for Xcode`. Get it from [this page](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode)

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove "Network Link Conditioner", open "System Preferences", press CTRL and click the "Network Link Conditioner" icon. Select "Remove".
2. Restart your computer
3. Download the dmg "Hardware IO tools" for your XCode version from https://developer.apple.com/download/, you need to be logged in to do this.
4. Open it and install "Network Link Conditioner"
5. Restart your computer one last time.

Comment: This helped a ton. I had no idea it installed into System Preferences. Now I can finally open it after initially installing it before rebooting my machine.

Answer (score 1):

**Now accessible directly inside Xcode 14,** no need to add any tools for that.

[image]

Comment: Seems interesting. Does it work in iOS app on the simulator?

Comment: On device. For simulator, still need preference pane.