# Simulate network speeds using Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I am using Fiddler and want to simulate different network speeds

Is there any published data that I can use to simulate different speeds using the delay value ?

Following is default code of Fiddler to simulate 56kb modem speed.

```
if (m_SimulateModem) {
    // Delay sends by 300ms per KB uploaded.
    oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "300"; 
    // Delay receives by 150ms per KB downloaded.
    oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "150"; 
}
```

I want the delay values for 256kbps, 512kbps, 1Mbps etc...

Comment: If you came here looking for throttling in fiddler as I did, note the above JavaScript code can be found by clicking the Rules menu ==> Customize Rules... Then find the text 'm_simulateModem' near line 189. Adjust these values to delay each Kb of data by x milliseconds.

Comment: @Zymotik - thanks for the shortcut - another tip for those adjusting these values for throttling - every time you save CustomRules.js Fiddler will turn off the Rules | Performance | Simulate Modem Speeds flag. You need to turn it back on if you want your new upload/download delays to apply.

Comment: @Zymotik & Drew: Thanks for those comments, that really helped me, as I couldn't work out how to change the speeds and then why they were not taking effect.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is simply a math problem.

Assuming that content is available instantly (e.g. you're playing it back from the AutoResponder) then the only delay is controlled by **request-trickle-delay** and **response-trickle-delay** flags.

There are 1000 milliseconds per second.

So, if you want to gate the connection to **1** megabyte per second, you would use a delay of **1** ms. If you want to gate it to **512** kilobyte per second, then use a delay of **2** ms. For **256** kilobytes per second, use a delay of **4** ms.

Keep in mind that bandwidth is often measured in **bits** per second rather than **bytes** per second. So if your goal is to measure things in *bits-per-second*, then multiply each value by **8**.

Comment: Thanks Eric. 
I guess this plugin for Fiddler does the same:
http://www.logic-worx.com/index.php/tools-and-apps/fiddler-connection-simulator/

Comment: Can't beat getting an answer from the man who wrote the software! This is one of the reasons I love SO...

Comment: Is it possible to set fractional trickle delays? I tried setting to "0.5" to get 2056KBs and it seemed to lock up the connection.

Comment: @JarrodSmith: Not today, no; Fiddler interprets the value as an Integer. I expect Fiddler's bandwidth-emulation features to get richer in the future.

Answer (score 38):

I made changes to request-trickle-delay and response-trickle-delay that EricLaw Recommended.
I used SpeedTest.Net to valaidate the changes I made.  They didn't match up perfectly.  For example I expected that if I set Trickle Delay values to 8 I would get download speed of 1 Mbps, but actually got 2.05 Mbps.  Based on EricLaw's answer at least I was able to identify a pattern.  Thanks Eric.

After each change to the Fiddler CustomerRule.js file I re-enabled "Simulate Modem Speed".  FYI, when you make a change to the CustomerRule.js file the "Simulate Modem Speed" is disabled. So you must re-enable the setting.

I added a few images of results from SpeedTest.net.

Below are the results for each setting change:

[image]

Fiddler Settings

[image]

Here I set request-trickle-delay and response-trickle-delay to 16.  As you can see I received 1.03 Mbps

[image]

Here I set request-trickle-delay and response-trickle-delay to 32.  As you can see I received 0.52 Mbps

[image]

Comment: How did you managed to affect speedtest.net using Fiddler? In my case it affect webpages download, images download etc., [but not speedtest.net](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39863388/2594597)

Comment: @Leonid Vasilyev
In Firefox you have to set up proxy manually. Automatic detection doen't work.

Comment: When experimenting with the script's settings you can change the `m_SimulateModem` declaration to default to `true` so it is enabled after the script loads.  Just remember to turn it back to `false` after you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I wanted to add some information here to make Fiddler throttling a little more user friendly. We are going to create a new menu under Rules with a bunch of modem speeds to select.

Click Rules -> Customize Rules option

[image: Customize Rules menu option (CTRL+R)]

Search for the declaration of `m_SimulateModem` which looks like:

`public static var m_SimulateModem: Boolean`

and replace it with a `RulesString`.

```cs
    // Cause Fiddler Classic to delay HTTP traffic to simulate typical modem conditions
    RulesString("Simulate &Modem Speeds", true) 
    BindPref("fiddlerscript.ephemeral.ModemSpeed")
    RulesStringValue(0,"5&6 kbps", "56")
    RulesStringValue(1,"&128 kbps", "128")
    RulesStringValue(2,"&256 kbps", "256")
    RulesStringValue(3,"&512 kbps", "512")
    RulesStringValue(4,"1 &mbps", "1m")
    var m_SimulateModem: String = null;
```

Search the rules again for `m_SimulateModem`, we are looking for the `if` statement where trickle is applied. Remove the `if` block and swap it for the following case statement:

```cs
switch (m_SimulateModem) {

    case "56": // 56kbps
        oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "760"; 
        oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "440";         
        break;
    
    case "128": // 128kbps
        oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "380"; 
        oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "220";             
        break;
    
    case "256": // 256kbps
        oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "190"; 
        oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "110";         
        break;
    
    case "512": // 512kbps
        oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "95"; 
        oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "55";          
        break;
    
    case "1m": // 1 mbps
        oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "46"; 
        oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "27";          
        break;
    
    case null:          
    default:
        break;
}
```

Save your rules file. You will now have an option under `Rules -> Simulate modem speeds` with various throttling options:

[image: Throttling speeds to 512kbps]

The numbers have been massaged using Speed Test to get close to the desired speeds in real life.

[image: Speed Test showing 512kbps throttling]

Bonus points: try viewing your favourite internet sites with throttling at 56kbps.