# Simulate web service slowdown using fiddler

Tags: performance, web-services, http, fiddler

Our web site relies on a number of third party web services. Recently one of these web services suffered a severe slow down causing numerous issues. I want to debug this today(the service is no longer being slow) so I need a way to simulate one of the web services being slow (not all web services but just one particular one).

I know I can [simulate a **network** slow down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276669/simulate-network-speeds-using-fiddler). How do I simulate one service slowing down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to do this by altering the Custom rules in fiddler:

[image]

If you edit the `OnBeforeResponse` function thus:

```js
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.myhost.com")){
        oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "400";
    }
    if (m_ShowTimestamp){
        oSession["ui-customcolumn"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss.ffff") + " " + oSession["ui-customcolumn"]; 
    }

    if (m_ShowTTLB){
        oSession["ui-customcolumn"] = oSession.oResponse.iTTLB + "ms " + oSession["ui-customcolumn"]; 
    }

    if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304){
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
    }
}
```

The important bit being:

```js
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.myhost.com")){
     oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "400";
}
```

The `400` value is *400ms per KB downloaded* (my web service has a loonnngg timeout)

with help from [Performance Testing on telerik web site](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/fiddlerscript/perftesting) and [FiddlerScript CookBook](http://fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp)

Comment: Alternatively, create an AutoResponder rule with match text of `www.myhost.com` and an action of `*flag:response-trickle-delay=400`.

Comment: Hey @EricLaw, Happy to have another answer if there is another/better way to do this?