# How to delay script/asset loading in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, delay, web-performance

Is there any way to add a time delay to a script/asset loading in the Google Chrome Browser via the Chrome Developer Tools? Or to block a script loading entirely?

The reason I want to do this is to see how a site performs when a script/asset suffers from delayed loading or failed loading.

Comment: You can do this [using Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276669/simulate-network-speeds-using-fiddler)

Answer (score 7):

In Chrome Developer Tools when you are in the Network you can add custom throttling. You can specify download and upload speed as well as request latency. But this will apply to all resources and not only to a specific one.

For delaying individual URLs on any page, you can use a **Chrome extension** (since it can intercept browser requests). I use [**URL Throttler** - Chrome extension webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-throttler/kpkeghonflnkockcnaegmphgdldfnden).

Answer (score 3):

This **DevTools extension** can fit your requirements. It's a Chrome/Firefox DevTools extension that can simulate http request delay for any configurable URL:
[**HTTP Request Blocker and Delayer** - Chrome devtools extension webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-request-blocker-and/klhfgmmihbgojnnbhdbnefjmiidlgfld?hl=en-GB&authuser=0)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Unfortunately, the plugin below is not available anymore.**

If the asset is a third party or hosted on a different domain, there is a Chrome plugin that's designed to test what you are calling loading delays, that are also called SPOF (Single Point Of Failure). It might not be very intuitive at first use, but it's very helpful :

The plugin is called SPOF-O-Matic and can be found here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spof-o-matic/plikhggfbplemddobondkeogomgoodeg

Comment: Sadly, the plug-in or extension above is not available anymore (dates 2012), but its source code seems to live on [GitHub pmeenan/spof-o-matic](https://github.com/pmeenan/spof-o-matic)

Answer (score 2):

Following solutions have nothing with Chrome Devtools but they work.

If you don't mind redirects then you can try [Slowwly](http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/) or [deelay.me](http://www.deelay.me/).

Other alternative for non-windows OS is [Comcast](https://github.com/tylertreat/comcast).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Requestly Browser Extension or Desktop App](https://requestly.io)  to modify your network requests. [Delaying/Throttling scripts](https://requestly.io/blog/adding-delay-to-network-requests/) is one of the use-cases amongst many already supported in Requestly.

Here's how you can do it. Once you install Requestly, Use [the Delay Request feature](https://requestly.io/feature/delay-request/).

### Create New Rule & Select Delay Rule Type

[image: Select Delay Request Rule Type]

### Define URL (or URL Pattern) and the delay value

[image: Delay Request Rule Editor]

[This article](https://requestly.io/blog/adding-delay-to-network-requests/) explains 3 different approaches to add delay/throttle APIs (or network requests). However, in your case Requestly extension based approach should work best.

*PS - I built Requestly.*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by combining multiple resources.

I use http://www.deelay.me/ to generate the delayed url.

I then combine it with requestly extension (https://requestly.io/) to create a host replace rule to target a specific resource