# Throttling network speed using Fiddler is not working

Tags: fiddler

The problem I am facing is almost similar to the following thread:

[Unable to control the network bandwidth using fiddler in spite of custom rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513610/unable-to-control-the-network-bandwidth-using-fiddler-in-spite-of-custom-rules?rq=1)

I want to throttle my network speed by following the steps as mentioned in 
[Simulate network speeds using Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276669/simulate-network-speeds-using-fiddler)

But even after doing the above settings the network speed still remains the same.

I am mentioning the steps I followed to downgrade my internet speed:

1. Launched Fiddler
2. Navigated to Rules-> Customize Rules..
3. Found the below code and changed the value accordingly in CustomRules.js.

   if (m_SimulateModem) { // Delay sends by 300ms per KB uploaded.      oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "500"; // Delay receives by 150ms per KB     downloaded. oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "500"; }
4. Saved the file by Ctrl+S
5. Closed the file.
6. Checked the flag "Simulate Modem Speeds"
   Now ideally the speed should be very less somewhere around 2kb/s (If my calculations are not wrong)

But the download and Upload speeds are close to 10 MBPS when measured using Speedtest.net. I tried closing the browser, fiddler etc but nothing helped.

Can you please tell me If I am missing something?

Also one more thing after saving the file in Step 4 above, when I navigated to the file CustomRule.js in the installation folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2\Scripts) it still showed the old values as mentioned below:

```
if (m_SimulateModem) {
// Delay sends by 300ms per KB uploaded.
oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "300"; 
// Delay receives by 150ms per KB downloaded.
oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "150"; 
}
```

Please guide me if I am doing this in a wrong way, let me know if I need t provide any more info.

Thanks!!

Namit

Answer (score 2):

You can use other resources like [speedof.me](http://speedof.me/) to measure speed of connection through Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

SpeedTest.net uses Flash and writes directly to a socket, bypassing the proxy. You cannot use Fiddler to slow its traffic.