# Dropzone upload progress

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

When using Dropzone.js, and its `uploadprogress` event, the first time it fires the progress is 100.

I'm running it locally.

Is jumping straight to 100 normal? How could I test actual upload progress?

Answer (score 0):

While running on localhost even files with size of couple of megabytes can be uploaded so fast that there will be only one upload progress event triggered for whole file. To test the actual look&feel of your progress bar you better simulate slow network on your local machine.

Obviously, you can increase the limit of maximum allowed file size and try uploading gigabyte file, which is of course not always feasible. Or more simple way is to upload files from local slow storages:  old usb sticks, or some network mapped drives.

Here is some [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328568/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-chrome%20this%20post) where you can find some references of tools which will help you to simulate low network capacity.

Comment: The linked question is about simulated lowering of bandwinth in Chrome, while this is about a different topic. There is pertinent information there, but I would link and include the pertinent information with proper attribution.

Comment: This was my first reply, didn't know that need to underline obvious things.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running ur code locally.
Try to look for some software you can limit you bandwidth or else at least try across local area network using another machine, and upload some bigger file, you can see the progress slowly uploaded from 1 to 100.