# Chrome/Firefox extension to kill network communication?

Tags: networking, emulation, browser-extension

So I'm building a web app, and I want to emulate a network failure in browser to see if the client side javascript handles it gracefully. I know I can just disconnect my network connection, but that also disconnects my email, pandora, skype, all things that are marginally vital to my non-productivity. Is there an easy way to kill network communication for just one tab in either of these browser? Or (I'm in linux) can I block a single pid from network communication while still allowing the rest (even if it's the same program) through?

Edit: Shoot, I just realized that I'm working on localhost, and that may not apply for what I'm asking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate limited bandwidth from within Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328568/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Does menu **file -> work without connection** works for you? It should be in the firefox menu.

Comment: That works perfect (I admit, I use chrome and hadn't explored firefox as fully as I should have), thank you =D Edit - Shoot, that would work in theory, but as I'm working with a localhost apache installation, no go. =(

Comment: Oh! That's weird. So sorry anyway :/

Comment: It was a good suggestion, just not applicable in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use invalid proxy settings! I recall some plugins that let you easily change proxy profiles so you could even have a profile for "dead proxy" and enable ot whenever you want no Internet.

Turns out there are more sophisticated options: a dedicated [site blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh?hl=en) for Chrome. That way you could still use other sites that help your non-productivity while still blocking the desired one!