# Slow down internet for iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a random crash in my iOS app. This happens when on slow internet connection. My office internet speed is too fast.

For testing on simulator, I installed Network Link Conditioner as mentioned here: [Installing Apple's Network Link Conditioner Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659382/installing-apples-network-link-conditioner-tool)

Now the problem is that, I selected a slower connection profile but still I'm having the normal (fast) internet speed in simulator.

I also created my own profile and set the download bandwidth to 5kbps but still no use.

I have:
Mackbook retina, OSX 10.7.5,
XCode: 4.4.1

Restarting Xcode and Simulator also didn't work.

Are there any additional settings required for Network Link Conditioner? Or should I do something else to regenerate the crash? Any help?

Comment: If your Mac is hardwired, switch to wireless.  And maybe start 2-3 megadownloads in other windows.

Comment: @HotLicks I am on wireless and I already had tried this using torrents but it works randomly. 1-2 out of 10 tries.

Comment: what do you use as your server ? some, like nginx allow you to throttle bandwith on server side

Comment: I don't know too much about servers but I have a DSL connection with wifi router. The subscription is 20Mbps.

Comment: @AbdullahUmer Just cover your WiFi router with aluminum foil until the connection is very bad and thus slow. Also, try disabling the WiFi on your computer while your App is downloading and see how it reacts.
You can check the connection speed on the computer by holding down ALT button and clicking on the wifi. Then it will tell you the transmit rate (mine shows 300 which is 300 Mbit/s).

Comment: To my knowledge the question is related to Software Development. Its related to Xcode iOS Simulator. Why has this been closed? Please explain. Please correct me if I'm in the wrong place.

Comment: I can't believe I'm reading these recommendations instead of a software feature that simulator should have.

Answer (score 51):

You can set the network to slow characteristic by testing on devices. Go to Settings -> Developer Settings -> Network Link Conditioner -> Enable. This is for iPhone/iPad running iOS 6
Network Link Conditioner is also available for the Mac in "Additional Tools for Xcode" for testing in the Simulator.

Note: It appears after device has been connected to Xcode, enabled for development and some app run on it.

Here's how you can test HORRIBLE network performance:
[image]

Comment: very strange. I have iOS 6 in my iPhone 4S and I dont see the Developer Settings in Settings. O.o

Comment: BTW, this won't help for the time being as I don't have the developer profile. For now I'm working on Simulator only.

Comment: @AbdullahUmer Sorry, but I assumed that you had a development profile.

Comment: It seems this settings are not there anymore in Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: @DirtyHenry It appears after you connect to XCode with cable and run code on the device.

Answer (score 7):

What about a development proxy server to simulate slow connections? One that looks promising is http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Thanks dude! But I'm in Saudi Arabia. Proxy servers are blocked here. I can't even access the mentioned website.

Comment: Charles is a proxy application that runs on your development machine. You can route all http calls via the Charles proxy in your internet settings. One of the things that Charles lets you do is simulate slow connections. i.e. it's not a proxy server and you should be able to use it in Saudi Arabia

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a ipad/iphone connected to your mac to reproduce the crash ?

ios6 contains a network link conditioner, too: http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2012/09/ios6-network-link-conditioner/

Comment: I can't because currently we haven't created the developer provisioning profile. So I can't deploy the app in any device. I have been testing on simulator. The internet speed was slow for some reason and I encountered the crash. This was happening since a couple of days but I couldn't understand whats the reason.