# Throttle internet speed manually

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

Is there an opportunity to throttle the mobile data speed in iOS 9 with an app manually? I want to try something out ...

Comment: If it's for testing purposes then yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12917987/2108547

Comment: Use the network link conditioner. On the simulator, this can be found in the "Hardware IO Tools" that you can find on Xcode's "Open Developer Tools" -  "More Developer Tools".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have developer mode enabled on your device, go to:

Settings -> Developer -> Network Link Conditioner