# Change connection to 3G or EDGE for testing slow internet connection

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an app that needs to be debugged under a slow connection. My issue is that I only own an iPhone 5 that uses LTE. I can disable LTE in my Settings for a 4G connection but this 4G connection is still to fast for my testing purposes. I would like to know if there is a way to programmatically force the testing iPhone into 3G or EDGE.

Comment: If you testing in the simulator would work you could use the [Network Link Conditioner Utility](http://9to5mac.com/2011/08/10/new-in-os-x-lion-network-link-conditioner-utility-lets-you-simulate-internet-and-bandwidth-conditions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to test flaky in addition to just going slow - you can simulate this with apple's network link conditioner and running your iPhone through your mac's internet connection (or run simulator). See [Installing Apple's Network Link Conditioner Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659382/installing-apples-network-link-conditioner-tool) .

If you really want some good testing, the best way to do it is look up your cell provider's coverage map and find some crappy locations. Test in those areas while driving in and out of range should weed out any broken network code you have. :)

Comment: Just to expand on this, on iOS 6, within the developer tools, there exists the option to use an in-built network link conditioner - nothing else is required.  [More Info](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2012/09/ios6-network-link-conditioner/)

Answer (score 3):

Network Link Conditioner also exists on the device in recent iOS builds, i'm not positive of when they added it.

But its present in Settings, under the Developer menu.

Answer (score 0):

> I can disable LTE in my Settings for a 4G connection but this 4G connection is still to fast for my testing purposes

LTE **is** (a kind of) 4G.

If you disable it, it will fall back to EDGE. Alternatively, you may switch to a Wi-Fi connection and slow it down (if your router has such a feature).