# Async NSURLConnection and keep-alive

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate, persistent-connection

I'm using NSURLConnection to perform a series of HTTP requests to the same host asynchronously, i. e. with `[initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:]` and a delegate.

When `connectionDidFinishLoading` notification comes to the delegate, I release my connection object, then initialize and initiate another one, to the same host. Question - will the underlying socket be reused? The `Connection:keep-alive` server header is there, but I have no way of making sure that it's being respected. I mean, the first connection is not officially "done" yet when it issues the notification. Or is it?

EDIT: [packet sniffing on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659382/installing-apples-network-link-conditioner-tool). PacketLogger ships along with hardware tools.

EDIT2: looks like it doesn't capture iOS simulator's activity.

Comment: I entered a bug report on this very same thing. There is no way to find out if a connection was held open or not. Note that flag you can set through NSURLConnection is only for HTTP/1.1. If you want to use the unofficial but widely used flag for 1.0, you must add it yourself to the header.

Comment: The server is 1.1, and it supports keep-alives alright. It's the client implementation that I'm worried about. Is there a packet sniffer for Mac?

Comment: There is some packet capture utility in the utilities download - I just saw it when I got the Network Link Conditioner a few days ago. Go to the Downloads section and you will see the adjunct downloads posted in October.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev - Is there anyway to disable keep-alive in NSURLConnection ?

Comment: Add a Connection:close header to the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some fiddling, got Wireshark to work on Mac. The TCP conversation is unbroken between requests - to me, this suggests keep-alive connections are working as advertised. iOS 7.0.3 on simulator.