# Simulate a lost connection in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a curl wrapper class for which I'm writing unit tests. The wrapper class is able to detect a lost or changed connection and restart a download accordingly. It does this by tracking how much data has been downloaded at fixed intervals.

Is there any way to manipulate the internet connection within a PHPUnit test?

Answer (score 1):

Write a `mock object` to wrap the network communication for unit testing.
In that mock class you can freely implement any kind of behaviour, like e.g. aborting the connection on a certain condition which would seem like a dropped connection to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly for a PHPUnit test, but maybe still related:

You can go hardcore mode: Pull your ethernet cable or turn off the wifi.

Seriously,

- On Mac OS X you can use [Apple Network Link Conditioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659382/installing-apples-network-link-conditioner-tool) - easy to use!

On Linux and Mac OS X you can try playing with `ipfw`

- `sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 56Kbit/s delay 200 plr 0.2`
- `sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 ip from any to any`

And turn it off with `sudo ipfw delete 1`

There is also [comcast](https://github.com/tylertreat/comcast) which is a really great and handy tool for such things!

Sadly I don't know what can be used on windows.

Also [this thread could be related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac)