# Video freezing when played over 4G; how to set internet speed programmatically?

Tags: android, video, network-connection, 4g

In my application I stream video via internet. It works great over WiFi but with 4G network the video is freezing. It's a weird beacuse at first I download video and after that stream from sd card but I'm sure that the problem is in network connection.

Is there any way set internet speed to a certain value programmatically or with third-party applications without root access?

I know about [mobiwol](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall&hl=en), [Bandwidth ruler Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bwr.free) and [BradyBound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oxplot.bradybound&hl=ru) but they are not helping.

With `android.telephony.TelephonyManager` I can get network type and thus determine the speed, but I didn't find how can I set the internet speed by this way.

**SOLUTION**

I was not found how to 4G network is related with video 'freezing' but I checked how exactly it saved on sd card and the file has been corrupted. I fixed this by adding check incoming file size and saved and if it false then overwritten the file. Thanks @Rolfツ

Comment: Setting internet speed programmatically, how would that work? In the best case scenario you can limit it to a certain speed, but you won't be able to speed it up or something like that...

Comment: @Rolfツ I don't want to increase the speed, but rather set a fixed level of network connection. Can I limit it?

Comment: Well in that case, you can't (unless you want to use root). There are however developer options to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026251/android-simulate-low-network-connectivity

Comment: @Rolfツ Thanks for link, but it work in emulator I need to set it on real device. If to use root how can I achieve this? Maybe I can set level via reflection in Java? Or this problem not related with network connection at all?

Comment: Even with reflection you can't probably limit it, due to the fact that this feature is not build into the Java interface. I also suspect you will run into permission problems if you try to do this. Root should work but it doesn't seem like network speed is your problem here. I think you need to verify if the downloaded file using WiFI is equal to the downloaded file over 4G.

Comment: @Rolfツ You suggest the file which download via 4G can be broken?

Comment: Depends on how your download works, but you should check it. If the files are the same then it should not impact video play-back.

Comment: @Rolfツ Thanks a lot, I'll check it