# Simulate poor network connection on android

Tags: android

It is possible to simulate a bad signal for a mobile network.
It is necessary to test the work of the android application in conditions of a bad network

Comment: Please refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026251/android-simulate-low-network-connectivity

Comment: Thank's i will try