# How to Make Genymotion emulator or android device to slow down internet speed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, genymotion

Need to test with slow connection to check the user facing issues in device and genymotion.
How to slow down WiFi connection or internet connection in mobile device and genymotion device.

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39093660/4949750) someone suggested setting up a [Crapify](https://github.com/bcoe/crapify) proxy on your computer and connecting to the internet throught it.

Comment: It is ok for genymotion @Amongalen thanks