# How to simulate slow/no network for Dart/Flutter's WebSocket, HttpClient and Socket?

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, networking

I need to simulate slow/no network for Dart/Flutter's HttpClient and Socket. However, I cannot find any guides on the network.

My naive idea is as follows. We can create `class SlowSocket implements Socket`, and use the delegate/decorator design pattern. For example, the `SlowSocket.add` method will be implemented as `Future.delayed(...).then(() => realSocket.add())`. I wonder whether this is ok? Or is there a simpler/better approach?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: see if this can help you out if you are testing using an Android emulator.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604490/7652758

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana thanks but I need to test on raw dart as well, so cannot use that simulator

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to setup a virtual machine like the Android Emulator which has this built-in. Otherwise depending on which platform you're doing your development you could use tools that simulate slow/no network (example for [Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/302299/what-tools-are-available-on-windows-to-simulate-emulate-network-issues)).

Chrome also offer this if you open the developer tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks, but I am hoping there is a lightweight solution since I want to run the tests continously

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Android Studio`, I've got you covered.

1. You may have to open AVD manger
   [image]
2. Click on "Pencil Icon(edit)"

   [image]
3. Go to advanced settings and then set the network type of your choice in speed and latency section:

   [image]

**Speeds for reference in increasing kbps:**

```
                            UP       DOWN
                      -------- ----------
    gsm   GSM/CSD         14.4       14.4
    hscsd HSCSD           14.4       57.6
    gprs  GPRS            28.8       57.6
    umts  UMTS/3G        384.0      384.0
    edge  EDGE/EGPRS     473.6      473.6
    hsdpa HSDPA         5760.0   13,980.0
    lte   LTE         58,000.0  173,000.0
    evdo  EVDO        75,000.0  280,000.0
    full  No limit           ∞          ∞
```