# How to limit Android device network speed for test purposes

Tags: android, performance, networking, limit

I am testing an Android application which had some problems with managing its content on low quality networks.
I am unable to verify if the problem still occurs, because with the speed of the network I have in my home (120mb/s), everything is already downloaded before I manage to start the reproduction route. Using the Android simulator is not an option in this case, as the reproduction route demands very quick action for the issue to appear.

I know that iOS has feature which allows users to limit network conditions, but I am unable to find a similar tool for Android.

**TL;DR**

Is there any way to simulate a bad network condition on actual Android device?

Comment: Look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236340/how-to-limit-speed-of-internet-connection-on-android-emulator

Using emulators there is a way.

Answer (score 6):

Try Throttly,it's a network link conditioner tool for Android.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.twocities.throttly

Comment: Works super fine, thanks !

Comment: Just to confirm it to other people, this is probably the easiest way to set test conditions without needing root or any debug commands. It uses the device's VPN capabilities.

Comment: Thanks! but the disadvantage is it doesn't allow you to define a custom profile. Even GPRS is too fast for my test case

Comment: provided play store link does not work anymore

Comment: the app is paid now

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.twocities.throttly.paid

Answer (score 3):

1. first you need a **rooted** Android device.
2. the method below limits **bandwidth**, the tc module in Android doesn't support set latency.

limit to 10kbit:

```
adb shell '
 tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 30
 tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10kbit
 tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 10kbit
 tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32  match ip dst 0.0.0.0/0 flowid 1:1
 tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32  match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 flowid 1:2
'
```

cancel the limit:

```
adb shell tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
```

Answer (score 2):

Give [BradyBound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oxplot.bradybound) a try. You need to have a rooted phone for this, though.

You can also try [this linux command](http://www.iplocation.net/tools/traffic-control.php). You'll need a Terminal Emulator for this in addition to root.

Comment: BradyBound limits only download speed.
Is there an app that limits upload speed?

Answer (score -1):

Computer Share WIFI, and then connect the phone WIFI, computer settings speed WIFI

Answer (score -1):

You could always deactivate the LTE/4G connection and use Edge/3G