# How to limit network speed on emulator (no root)?

Tags: android

I want to limit my network speed to emulate bad network in Android emulator.
I have tried to install BradyBound from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640407/how-to-limit-android-device-network-speed-for-test-purposes) topic, but it requires root access, which I don't have on emulator. Maybe exist another solution? Maybe via shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On android emulator click 3 dot at the right section. Then select cellular and choose network type.

[image]
[image]

Comment: oh my god) so simple!