# Have tool for test network android?

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to check some case https request with the weak network and timeout case. Any tools help my device in this condition ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should try [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/).

**UPDATE**

If you want to influence the network speed, then see the correct answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236340/how-to-limit-speed-of-internet-connection-on-android-emulator).

Comment: In this case, this question can be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236340/how-to-limit-speed-of-internet-connection-on-android-emulator

Comment: Thanks, @Gex it useful for me :)

Comment: Your welcome @TháiNgô . I updated my original answer, if this was what you were searching for, please feel free to mark as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/).

[Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) is a debug bridge for Android applications created by Facebook.

It integrates with the Chrome desktop browser’s Developer Tools.

With [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/), you can easily inspect your application — most notably, its network traffic.

It also allows you to easily inspect and edit SQLite databases and the shared preferences in your app.

Comment: Thanks, @Amit Shekhar

Answer (score 0):

I think [AppSpector](https://appspector.com/) will helpful for you. It's a new tool to inspect the app remotely. It contains tools for watching HTTP requests and responses, tools for watching SQLite database and executing some SQL request during development.