# How to control internet speed in android, IOS apps?

Tags: android, ios, networkx, limit, bandwidth

I need to control internet speed when I do load testing for Android/IOS apps. Is there any apps for non rooted devices which controls bandwidth?
Any idea to develop a simple app?
At least in developer mode?

Comment: In iOS you can go to the developer settings in the settings app and use the link conditioner

Comment: thanks for the reply... any idea for android?

Answer (score 1):

For android physical device
You can try

- Swiching to 2g mode from settings
- Connecting to wifi with proxy and control that in windows

For android emulator
You can control bandwidth from emulator advanced settings

[How to limit speed of internet connection on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236340/how-to-limit-speed-of-internet-connection-on-android-emulator)